# MySQL JSON column parsed on Linux but not Windows

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql2

There exists a database with a `users` table containing 2 columns, `userId` and `saved`. `userId` is a simple increment, and `saved` is JSON data.

There exists a single row:

userId: 1, saved: "{"value": 1}"

When the following code is run on Windows

```js
    const mysql = require('mysql2');
    
    async function start() {
        const connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            database: 'database'
        });
        connection.query('SELECT saved FROM users WHERE userId = 1', function(err, results, fields) {
            console.log(results);
        })
    }
    
    start();
```

`[ TextRow { saved: '{"value": 1}' } ]` is displayed on Windows

`[ TextRow { saved: { value: 1 } } ]` is displayed on Linux

What exactly is going on here that parses my JSON on Linux but not on Windows?

---

The MySQL versions are both different

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.33, for Linux (x86_64)

mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.17-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64)

I'm unsure how I'd get both of them to the same version. The Windows machine is running XAMPP and it seems like a pain to mess with. I'm trying right now to get the same versions of both installed.

The `users` table is InnoDB utf8mb4_general_ci

| field | type |
| --- | --- |
| userId | int(10) |
| saved | longtext utf8mb4_bin |

I'm not actually using this code for anything, I use an ORM to do this but it uses mysql2 to do querying and I traced the error down to mysql2 and just copy-pasted the example code from GitHub to test if it was the culprit. I would use promise-based code if I was actually working with it.

MySQL2 is indeed the same version on both platforms. 2.2.5.

Interestingly the issue doesn't occur with the mysql package. I assume this indicates something funky going on with the package itself.

Comment: Are both MySql Servers the very same version?

Comment: What's the DB schema in both cases?

Comment: Sorry for the off-topic question. I'm curious why people use callbacks when `mysql2/promise` is also available. Is it a preference or just an older habit?

Comment: I would also throw in, is the mysql2 package version identical for both? I think automatically decoding JSON fields is not a feature that was in mysql2 from the start.

Comment: I added more to the bottom of the post to address everything said so far as there's a lot. I'm thinking it's a package issue as it doesn't occur with mysql but does with mysql2.

Comment: Can you add your package.json dependencies (specifically the version number of mysql2 from each). I'm also interested in the table definitions.

Comment: It does seem to have something to do with the database versions. I got MySQL 8.0.23 setup and suddenly the data is coming back parsed.